# Exercise on sequences using epsilon

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to solve the following exercise

given $ε>0$, calculate $m_ε∈ℕ$ such that for all $n≥m_ε$ it is verified that $|x_n-x|<ε$.

In this particular case we have that

$x_n= (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^n$ and $x=0$

It is clear that we can consider

$x_n-x = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^n$

One idea I had in mind is the following For $x-1≥0$ it is verified that $x^n=(1+(x+1))^n≥1+n(x-1)$, I thought I would use this equality conveniently to try to arrive at a value such that $n≥m_ε$. However, it is not clear to me how to make use of the above, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$$\sqrt2^{\,n}=\bigl(1+\left(\sqrt2-1\right)\bigr)^n\geqslant n\left(\sqrt2-1\right)$$and therefore$$\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^n\leqslant\frac1{n\left(\sqrt2-1\right)}.$$So, take$$m_\varepsilon=\left\lceil\frac1{n\left(\sqrt2-1\right)\varepsilon}\right\rceil.$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, we seek $m_\epsilon$ such that $|x_n-x|\lt\epsilon$ for $n\ge m_\epsilon$

We have,

$$|x_n-x|=\left|(1/\sqrt 2)^n-0\right|=(1/\sqrt 2)^n\lt\epsilon\iff (\sqrt 2)^n\gt\epsilon$$

If $\epsilon\lt\sqrt 2$, we can just choose $m_\epsilon=1$

If $\epsilon\ge\sqrt 2$, then we have $(\sqrt 2)^n\gt\epsilon\iff 2^n\gt\epsilon^2\iff n\gt\log_2(\epsilon^2)=2\log_2\epsilon$, so choose $m_\epsilon=1+2\log_2\epsilon$